# Spring mvc @DateTimeFormat not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I just added a jQuery date picker to my simple page made in jsp. Using Spring mvc 4.0.0. I would like to have java.util.Date field in my model class and let spring to convert the date String coming from the front end to date. My issue is that, if i have

```
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yy")
 private Date startDate;
```

In my model class I receive null value in my spring controller. (The startDate setter is not called neither) If i change the startDate to be a simple String, than the value is populated correctly and in the controller i am able to retrieve the startDate string. Could you please advice what am I missing?

Was trying to follow the http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/05/21/binding-date-form-input-on-spring-mvc/ seems that no other tricks has been used to convert the String to Date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern=dd/MM/YY)
private Date startDate;
```

Maybe it's not working with Date, have you tried using DateTime instead?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but still no joy. The Date field is still null.

Comment: Are you using jodatime ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: I read somewhere that you need to include jodatime in classpath to use this annotation, but not sure. Have you even tried with dd/MM/yyyy in pattern?

Comment: Ohh i see your point. JodaTime should be included already in Spring 4 i hope. Will double check, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Have you activated annotation-driver in your configuration?

Comment: Yes exactly. Another annotations such as @Controller etc. etc. are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoule put @DateTimeFormat under the @RequestMapping, like below:

`@RequestMapping
public String someMethod(@RequestParam(value="date", required=false)@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/YY") Date date)`