# Passing Parameters in Spring MVC 4.0

Tags: spring-mvc, httprequest, spring-4

I have read multiple posts, and have yet to find an answer to my issue.  I have the following controller using Spring 4.

Because of the examples I have found, I have gleaned how to use my WellTest POJO to automatically bind via the @RequestParam.  I can tell you that many times the "Experts" assume way too much of what they themselves do easily every day when explaining this stuff, and I am not a newby by any means.  However, I don't work services very much and in Spring's case, sometimes your only as good as your last version you used.  Mine was around 2.5 or so.

Here is my controller method - it's just for testing the passing of Variables.

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{WellTestID}", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
public String setWellTestByWellTestID( @RequestParam(defaultValue = "99999")  Long wellTestID, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "99999")  Long wellFacilityID, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "101")  int operatorPersonID, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "67845")  int durationSeconds, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "100")  long grossRate, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "400")  long waterCut, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "30")  long percentGas, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "500")  long temperature, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "60")  long flowLinePressure, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "50")  long casingPressure, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0")   int allocation, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "3")   int wellTestTypeID,  
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "you")  String createUser,
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "me-me")  String lastModifiedUser,
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "4-4-2014") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date createDate,              
    WellTest wellTest) throws IOException 
{
    /* try {
        wellTestService.updateWellTest(wellTest);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    
    String param1 = new String(wellFacilityID.toString());

    return param1; 
}
```

The app is for retrieving and editing Well Tests for Oil Wells.  I was able to get every parameter to pass, except when I used a Date datatype.  I am positive it's related to conversion within the binding, but the service will not even error within debugger - The error tells me the request is not syntactically correct and it never gets to the request method.

The error is...

```
Blockquote
400 Bad Request Show explanation Loading time: 18
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6
Response headers 
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Content-Language: 
Content-Type: text/html 
Date: Wed, 17 Sep 2014 21:29:47 GMT 
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1105
```

My question is simple, and please if you are going to comment or answer, be thorough in both.  Please assume i know next to nothing, and you are the one who can explain it.

How are passed parameters datatypes converted within Spring MVC?  Please explain what to do as well as the concepts behind the why.

Comment: Holy code formatting, Batman.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know how to use this forum effectively yet...

Comment: The default value you specify for your date doesn't match the pattern defined in the Spring 4.1 JavaDoc for DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE.  Perhaps the date you are passing in is also not adhering to the patern.  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE

Comment: Also, it is quite likely that if you provide the raw details of your HTTP request, that someone will be able to assist you quite quickly.  The more details you provide, the easier it is to help.

Comment: Those are the headers, I was able to get all posts to work by changing all my Date members to String in the Domain Class WellTest.  I will add it.  I'm not seeking help about any other area of this isaue - That is, the marshalling and unmarshalling of Data Types via Spring MVC.  Since Dates are a common argument for practically any service call, if someone could explain (or point to a document - reading your link right after this) what is necessary for this to happen, it would mean  I could quit swapping Date objects for Strings before saving to the database - Thanks Nicholas!

Comment: I think I could cure it by properly applying the @DateTimeFormat annotation, but I need a complete understanding of using a simple month-day-year Time format I guess.  It's posts like this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971831/spring-mvc-datetimeformat-not-working-as-expected) that are encouraging, but do not rise to a level of understanding I can use in a practical sense.

Comment: Spring makes Services pretty boilerplate, but I don't have the spare time to overcome the simple stuff in Spring that drives people mad.  Yes, I'm a complainer!  I waste too much time on open source looking for implementation details for concepts that explain nicely, but are mysterious in their implementations. Is there a Spring engineer who can point to an article that contains all the hidden requirements and details regarding Spring RESTFul Services with MVC?  And isn't a dry API doc?

Comment: Here is an example of what I am taliking about. (http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/86986-datetimeformat-for-pathvariable-not-converting) where even a knowlegable "expert" doesn't get the question and keeps pounding an answer home, but it's incorrect.  This answer doesn't help me though, unless I now try to understand just how to add another bean to Spring 4 MVC (have you looked at the zoo of Spring configurations lately?), which is completely different from the Spring examples in this thread.  See?  It just goes on and on...  Into the ether, it seems.